# When I use the Genius API, it doesn't give me the full lyrics

Tags: python, discord.py, genius-api

When i run this code (discord.py), i do not get the full lyrics:

```
@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
    song = genius.search_song(arg2, arg1)
    print(song)
    embedgenius = discord.Embed(title=arg2.capitalize(), description=arg1.capitalize(), colour=0x69ff00)
    embedgenius.add_field(name="Lyrics:", value=song)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedgenius)
```

I just get that:

example Polo G - Rapstar:

```
"RAPSTAR" by Polo G:
[Intro]
(Shout out my n**** Synco)

[Chorus]
Uh (Tuned up), copped a BMW, new deposit, I picked up a...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the song as the value, not the lyrics.

> embedgenius.add_field(name="Lyrics:", value=song)

You're basically printing the song object and it having parts of the lyrics in it is just a coincidence. To print the lyrics of a song use `song.lyrics`. However you should keep in mind that embed fields are limited to 1024 characters.

---

```py
@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
    song = genius.search_song(arg2, arg1)
    print(song.lyrics)
    embedgenius = discord.Embed(title=arg2.capitalize(), description=arg1.capitalize(), colour=0x69ff00)
    embedgenius.add_field(name="Lyrics:", value=song.lyrics)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedgenius)
```